# Удаление пустых элементов списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Извините за глупый вопрос, но как удалить пустые элементы из списка в пайтоне?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Для начала стоит формализовать, что такое "пустой" элемент.

"Пустыми" можно считать многие элементы, например,

```
[], (), {}, set(), ''
```

в том числе

```
None, 0, 0.0, 0j, False
```

Если требуется выбросить из коллекции все такие элементы, то можно воспользоваться генератором списка

```
[value for value in values if value]
```

Или, если список не требуется, генераторным выражением:

```
(value for value in values if value)
```

Если правило определения "пустого" элемента более сложное, достаточно описать это правило после оператора `if` в указанных выше выражениях, например,

```
[value for value in values if value != [None]]
```

оставит в списке элементы, которыне не равны списку, содержащему `None` (важно заметить, что такой список будет пропущен в итоговый набор в первых случаях).

Answer (score 8):

Следующий способ будет быстрее (для python 2.7):

```
filter(None, mylist)
```

а если вы используете python3, то необходимо использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
list(filter(None, mylist))
```

так как filter на python3 возвращает генератор

Answer (score 7):

Например, через [генератор списков](http://habrahabr.ru/post/30232/):

`mylist = [x for x in mylist if x]`

Вместо последнего `x` можно написать `x is not None`, если нули и пустые строки не должны считаться пустыми элементами.

Comment: http://ideone.com/3QpTI0 тоже так думал. Почему не работает ? Не подскажете ?

Comment: @ReinRaus Потому что условием `x is not None` проверяется, что список `x` не None, а он не None, он список :) В результате все элементы и попадают.

http://ideone.com/iT2Ar8

Comment: тьфу. я невнимателен. опечатался и минут 5 втыкал что не так :)