# Значение None python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему это работет так, ведь значение `None` работает по эквивалетности как и `null`, а в переменной `a` нету никаких значение.

По идеи же должно получиться `True` т.к. значение `None` ничего не имеет или равно `0` или `False` , но по чему то при вводе таких данных в переменную `a` возвращается `False` не могли бы объяснить почему так происходит.

```
>>> a = ""
>>> a == None
False
>>> a = "0"
>>> a == None
False
>>> a = 0
>>> a == None
False
>>>
```

Comment: Ничего подобного, в переменной `a` есть очень даже конкретные значения — конкретная пустая строка, конкретная строка с одним символом ноль и конкретное число ноль. Это не является отсутствием значения

Comment: Всё то же самое относится и к null во всех адекватных языках программирования. Языки, в которых null и ноль равны, адекватными не являются :) (кроме указателей в си разве что, там контекст другой)

Comment: @andreymal просто казалось что тип раз `null`, то это ноль по смыслу, сори за тупость :)

Comment: «ноль по смыслу» вам вернёт `bool(a)`. В логических выражениях (`if` например) значения автоматически интерпретируются как «ноль по смыслу». См. также [вопрос про пустые элементы в питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422461)

Comment: @andreymal @Sergey Gornostaev написал что в первом случае у меня в `a` находится пустая строка а `None`  это же тоже пустой элемент разве нет?

Comment: технически, None в питоне — это такое же конкретное значение, как и ноль, как и пустая строка, как и всё остальное. Если точнее, None — экземпляр класса-синглтона NoneType. Просто его, условно говоря, все договорились считать пустым. Но None и пустая строка это всё равно разные и никак не равные друг другу значения, хоть и оба «нули по смыслу». `a == None` даст False, зато `bool(a) == bool(None)` даст True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` у вас это имя. Используя `=` оператор вы прикрепляете это имя к разным объектам (пустая строка `''`, строка с символом `'0'` (U+0030), целое число `0` — объекты создаются соответствующими константами в исходном коде). Строки это объекты типа str в Питоне. Целое число это объект типа int.

`a == None` сравнивает эти объекты с None объектом. Никакой объект типа str или  int не может быть равен None. В сторону, None это также объект в Питоне (с типом NoneType). Он существует в единственном экземпляре в программе, поэтому сравнивать следует используя `is` оператор: `a is None` (is говорит тот же объект или нет. Назначение `==` сравнивать *значения* объектов).

Вероятно вас интересовало понятие "truthiness" в Питоне (значение в булевом контексте) и действительно пустая строка (как и другие пустые контейнеры) и 0 целое число являются Falsey в Питоне:

```
if not a:
    print(f'{a!r} is Falsey')
```

See [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Обратите внимание `'0'` — непустая строка, поэтому `bool('0') is True`.  Питон является сильно типизированным языком. Строка в число или в None объект неявно *не превратится*. Сами имена, такие как `a` могут ссылаться на любой объект в разное время. Но имя обязано ссылаться на какой-нибудь объект, иначе `NameError` получите.

Comment: А это так же будет работа в `PyQt` с функцией `QLineEdit` если в ее значение ничего не вводить ?

Comment: @Twiss: что значит "так же"? QLineEdit (класс) позволяет создать однострочный редактор (GUI элемент).  Какое отношение это имеет к текущему вопросу?

Comment: Допустим у меня есть `a = QLineEdit` мне нужно вывести значение через `a.text()`, а если в `a.text()` ничего не будет вписано то она все равно не будет `None`?

Comment: @Twiss что методы объекта возвращают зависит от конкретного класса (язык никаких ограничений здесь не вводит). Смотрите документацию для QLineEdit, экспериментируйте в Python REPL. Кстати, имя QLineEdit ссылается на сам класс. Не путайте класс и экземпляры, которые он создаёт. Если что-то не ясно, спрашивайте (лучше отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задать, если проблема напрямую не связана с текущим ответом)

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае в переменной `a` находится пустая строка. Во втором строка с символом ноль. В третьем число 0. Во всех трёх случаях в переменной что-то есть.

Comment: @Twiss в сторону: многих ошибок можно избежать, если  не думать о переменных в Питоне как о коробках, в которых что-то находится, а представлять имена как бирки, которые крепятся к объектам. Это упрощает модель (многие вещи легче объяснить). Вот [картинки, которые иллюстрируют разницу](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).